# Is there a good web application for manipulating pdf files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, web-applications

Is there a good web application for manipulating a PDF files? For example, drag and drop images to it and save for future reference, then remove the dropped images anytime etc. I want to integrate it with my existing web application also.

EDIT:

These links I have came across while searching. Might be useful for someone searching the same.:)

- [PDFescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/)
- [Crocodoc](https://crocodoc.com/)
- A.nnotate.com(a.nnotate.com)
- GroupDocs Annotation(groupdocs.com/apps/annotation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mozilla has [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which renders PDF files using HTML5. This same script is used in the built-in PDF reader of recent Firefox browsers.

It's experimental, but you could hack the code and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just an online tool which will spit the pdf file use - [Sejda](http://www.sejda.com/)
there is a lot of other tools available online too

PDF Sharp will allow you to do all sort of manipulation that you require. It is open source, free to use. You can download it from [here..](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1)

Features include

```
 Creates PDF documents on the fly from any .Net language
 Easy to understand object model to compose documents
 One source code for drawing on a PDF page as well as in a window or on the printer
 Modify, merge, and split existing PDF files
 Images with transparency (color mask, monochrome mask, alpha mask)
 Newly designed from scratch and written entirely in C#
 The graphical classes go well with .Net
```